# STCDO upper tranche still paying coupons even after all default

Tags: credit

We assume :

- that a CDO on $n$ names, with a maturity $T$
- that at a time $\tau<T$ before the maturity of the CDO, these $n$ names have defaulted,
- that we are the protection buyer of the 22-100 tranche,
- that the full loss of this portfolio is 60,
- all the preceding quantities are expressed in percentage of the nominal of the underlying debt portfolio of this CDO.

This is where the question comes :

**Will we still continue to pay a premium even between $\tau$ and $T$ ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on the contractual specification. In general, **you do not  need to pay any premium between $\tau$ and $T$.**

For a CDO with attachment and detachment levels $A$ and $D$. Let $L(t)$ be the cumulative loss of the basket, that is,
\begin{align*}
L(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_i(1-R_i) 1_{\tau_i \le t},
\end{align*}
where $\tau_i$ is the default time, $N_i$ is the notional amount, and $R_i$ is the recovery rate, for the $i^{th}$ entity. Moreover, let 
$L_{[A,\, D]}(t)$ be the tranche loss amount, that is,
\begin{align*}
L_{[A,\, D]}(t) &= \min\big(\max(L(t)-A, \,0), \, D-A \big)\\
&=\max\big(L(t)-A, \,0 \big) - \max\big(L(t)-D, \,0 \big).
\end{align*}
Then, the premium payment at time $t_j$ is based on the notional amount given by
\begin{align*}
\min\bigg(\big(D-A\big) - L_{[A,\, D]}(t_j),\, \sum_{i=1}^n N_i 1_{\tau_i > t_j}\bigg),\tag{1}
\end{align*}
which turns to zero on any premium payment date after $\tau = \max_{i=1}^n \tau_i$.

> EDIT after comments.

The second term $\sum_{i=1}^n N_i 1_{\tau_i > t_j}$ in $(1)$ is added so that, for a CDS index, the premium notional is not more than the underlying basket notional.

Note that, for an index (i.e, whole tranche $[0, 100\,\%]$), $L_{[A,\, D]}(t)=L(t)$. 
Assuming that the first $i_0$ entities, where $1\le i_0 < n$, have defaulted before the premium payment date $t_j$, while the remaining $n-i_0$ entities have not defaulted yet, then the notional for the premium payment on date $t_j$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\min\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n N_i-\sum_{i=1}^{i_0}N_i(1-R_i),\, \sum_{i=i_0+1}^n N_i\bigg) &= \min\bigg(\sum_{i=i_0+1}^n N_i +\sum_{i=1}^{i_0} N_i R_i,\, \sum_{i=i_0+1}^n N_i\bigg)\\
&=\sum_{i=i_0+1}^n N_i.
\end{align*}

Comment: for simplicity, I assume $N_i=\frac{1}{n}$ and $R_i=R$. It means that if I look at the tranche [0,100\% ] and that **$n-1$ names have defaulted**, premium payment payment for the tranche is paid over the following notional amount :
$$ N_{0-100} \left(1-(1-R)\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = R+\frac{1}{n}(1-R) $$
where as for the index over these names, premium payment will be based on the following notional amount :
$$ N_{\text{index}} = 1-\frac{n-1}{n} = \frac{1}{n} $$
So after $n-1$ defaulted you have that : $$ 0\approx N_{\text{index}} << N_{0-100} \approx R$$
**is that ok for market participants ?**

Comment: @MJ73550: See my edit above. You have a good question, and that is is the reason I have the extra term $\sum_{i=1}^n N_i 1_{\tau_i > t_j}$ in (1). In your example, after $n-1$ names defaulted, the notional should be $\min\left(1-(1-R)\frac{n-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}$, as it should be in market practice. Note that we have a minimum operator here.